# Как адекватно преобразовать Stream в список в Java 7?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, потоки-данных, path

поскольку в 1.7 джаве ещё нет ссылок на конструкторы или условий с лямбдой то я не могу воспользоваться методами,предложенными в интернете...но мне нужно преобразовать Stream в String[]...
изменить тип стрима или тип списка нельзя...
Воспользовался вот такой штукой:

```
String[] files = Files.list(Paths.get(folder)).toArray(new IntFunction<String[]> () {
  @Override
  public String[] apply(int value) {
    return new String[value];
  }
});
```

```
и получил java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

Comment: В Java 7 нет ни метода `list` в класса [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), ни вообще `Stream`.

Comment: Скажите, а какой результат выполнения этого кода вы ожидаете? Вы пытаетесь получить список файлов в каталоге?

Comment: Как нету?если бы не было,тогда бы компилятор жаловался,разве нет?

Comment: `@since   1.8`. Действительно нет.